# google adsense banner not full loaded

Tags: html, image, adsense, banner

I don't understand why my left and 2 right Google adsense banner are not fully loaded. I see only one piece of the image banner:

http://liberainformazione.it/

What I am doing wrong?
Can you help me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your images are loaded fully.
Your problem is your CSS styles.
The height of all those partly visible images is because you have a div inside your 200x200 div which gives the problem.
You have to check the css on your own, i just gave you the place to look for:)

I am not quit familiar with wordpress, but i just copied a small part of your html

```
<aside id="leftSidebar">
        <!--img src="wp-content/themes/base/images/left.png"/-->
<div id="adsense" style="height:200px;">
<div id="adsense-loader" style="display:block;">
    <script type="text/javascript"><!--
    google_ad_client = "ca-pub-9833138679608221";
    google_ad_slot = "5796741996";
    google_ad_width = 200;
    google_ad_height = 200;
    //-->
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com    /pagead/show_ads.js"></script>
    <ins style="display:inline-table;border:none;height:200px;margin:0;padding:0;position:relative;visibility:visible;width:200px">X<ins data-web-developer-element-ancestors-outline="true" id="aswift_2_anchor" style="display: block; border: medium none; height: 200px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; position: relative; visibility: visible; width: 200px; outline: 1px solid rgb(185, 74, 72);"><iframe allowtransparency="true" hspace="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" onload="var i=this.id,s=window.google_iframe_oncopy,H=s&amp;&amp;s.handlers,h=H&amp;&amp;H[i],w=this.contentWindow,d;try{d=w.document}catch(e){}if(h&amp;&amp;d&amp;&amp;(!d.body||!d.body.firstChild)){if(h.call){i+='.call';setTimeout(h,0)}else if(h.match){i+='.nav';w.location.replace(h)}s.log&amp;&amp;s.log.push(i)}" vspace="0" id="aswift_2" name="aswift_2" style="left: 0px; position: absolute; top: 0px;" frameborder="0" height="200" scrolling="no" width="200"></iframe></ins></ins>

</div>
```

When i use just this as source code, i get 2 squares, next to each other,
while left out the long rule, starting with ins...etc... the ad just shows up well.

I think your problem is OR your used wp-addon OR you have edited your templates the wrong way OR your wp-template has errors for this.

Answer (score 0):

Looks that someone steal your google ads..overlapping google ads with their ads:

this line:

```
<ins style="display:inline-table;border:none;height:200px;margin:0;padding:0;position:relative;visibility:visible;width:200px">X<ins data-web-developer-element-ancestors-outline="true" id="aswift_2_anchor" style="display: block; border: medium none; height: 200px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; position: relative; visibility: visible; width: 200px; outline: 1px solid rgb(185, 74, 72);"><iframe allowtransparency="true" hspace="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" onload="var i=this.id,s=window.google_iframe_oncopy,H=s&amp;&amp;s.handlers,h=H&amp;&amp;H[i],w=this.contentWindow,d;try{d=w.document}catch(e){}if(h&amp;&amp;d&amp;&amp;(!d.body||!d.body.firstChild)){if(h.call){i+='.call';setTimeout(h,0)}else if(h.match){i+='.nav';w.location.replace(h)}s.log&amp;&amp;s.log.push(i)}" vspace="0" id="aswift_2" name="aswift_2" style="left: 0px; position: absolute; top: 0px;" frameborder="0" height="200" scrolling="no" width="200"></iframe></ins></ins>
```